# English usage and grammatical correctness

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it correct to use "what's," "who's," and "why's," in a single sentence?

*Example:*

> She was perplexed at the "**what's**", "**who's**" and "**why's**" of the
>   situation, so much so that she lost her mental balance.

Comment: Why the apostrophes?  Whys and wherefores is a more common phrase.

Comment: @Tim But whos isn't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - please elucidate!

Comment: One general recommendation is that a word used as a word should be italicised and, if pluralised, have a non-italicised 's added. Thus << There are too many _however_'s in the second paragraph. >> This has been covered on ELU before. With very common examples (<< The whys and wherefores, and the ifs and buts, are explained fully in the next chapter. >> ), the requirement is often dropped.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence reads fine as-is, though I would make one suggestion.

The apostrophe in the "what's" indicates the possessive rather than the plural.  You would be better off removing the apostrophes; eg "whys" instead of "why's".